# How to set multiple tables on gatsby-source-dynamodb

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, gatsby

I'm trying to connect with Dynamodb in Gatsby tho, I can only access one table by gatsby-source-dynamodb.

My config file is below.

```
   {
     resolve: 'gatsby-source-dynamodb',
     options: {
       typeName: 'DynamoDB',
       accessKeyId: '*************', 
       secretAccessKey: ''*************',
       region: 'us-west-1',
       params: {
         TableName : "Jobs",
       }
     }
   },
```

Do you guys know how to set multiple tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I could resolve this problem with below config setting.

```
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-dynamodb',
      options: {
        typeName: 'DynamoJobs',
        accessKeyId: ''*********', 
        secretAccessKey: ''*********',
        region: 'us-west-1',
        params: {
          TableName : "Jobs",
          // OTHER PARAMS HERE
        }
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-dynamodb',
      options: {
        typeName: 'DynamoProjects',
        accessKeyId: '*********', 
        secretAccessKey: ''*********',
        region: 'us-west-1',
        params: {
          TableName : "Projects",
          // OTHER PARAMS HERE
        }
      }      
    },
```

Comment: As a result, I use Amplify instead of gatsby-source-dynamodb